# TextValidator showing browser validation messages when it is set to required

Tags: validation, material-ui, required-field

I'm using **TextValidator** from *react-material-ui-form-validator*, what I wanted was to display the **'*'** when an input is **required** in its input label. However, passing **required as "true" was taking browser validation rather than the validators being passed**.
So, one way was I update the label by appending '*' as "Label Name *". Which means for every element, I change the label text.
But, I would like to know about any option with which I can pass **required** but use the validators instead of browser validation?

Editable [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textvalidator-required-g6bhi), if you have a solution kindly update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, [`react-material-ui-form-validator`](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-material-ui-form-validator) uses [`react-form-validator-core`](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-form-validator-core) to generate its form.

And checking this [line](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-form-validator-core/blob/master/src/ValidatorForm.jsx#L161) shows that whatever props you pass to `ValidatorForm` (except `onSubmit`, `instantValidate`, `onError`, `debounceTime` and `children`) are passed down to `form` element.

This means you can use `novalidate` attribute to disable browser's validation.

```js
...
<ValidatorForm
  ref="form"
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  onError={(errors) => console.log(errors)}
  noValidate={true} // notice this
>
  <TextValidator
    label="Email"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    name="email"
    required // and this
    value={email}
    validators={["required", "isEmail"]}
    errorMessages={["this field is required", "email is not valid"]}
  />
  <DialogActions>
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </DialogActions>
</ValidatorForm>
```

[image: Edit TextValidator-required (forked)]